# Why does parsing give out only one 'title'?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm just starting to learn how to parse. From the website I need to get the names of the directions and the educational program (bachelor's degree, master's degree, etc...).
But at the output I get only one element.
Here is my code:

```
def get_HTML(url, params=None):
    request = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params = params) #params = get parameters

    return request

def get_Content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    eduPrograms = soup.find_all('div', class_= 'column-center_rasp')
    eduProgram = []
    for i in eduPrograms:
        eduProgram.append({
            'title':i.find('div', class_='headerEduPrograms').get_text()
        })
    print(eduProgram)
    
    eduDirection = soup.find_all('div', {'id': 'fak_id_7a3586aa7b32182f036c0dab143d2df8_493'})
    eduDirections = []
    for i in eduDirection:
        eduDirections.append({
            'title':i.find('div', class_='grpPeriod').get_text()
        })
    print(eduDirections)
    

def parse():
    html = get_HTML(URL)
    if (html.status_code) == 200:
        get_Content(html.text)

    else:
        print('Error')

parse()
```

At the output I get only:

> [{'title': 'Бакалавр'}]
> [{'title': '\n                                                                                                ИВТб-1301-04-00                                                                                             '}]

HTML from site(only for a eduDirection)

[image: HTML from site(only for a eduDirection)]

Comment: This is web scraping, not really parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`eduDirection` only has one match, there's no need to loop it.

In the loop, you're using `i.find()`, which just finds the first DIV with that class. You need to use `.find_all()` to find all of them.

```
    eduDirection = soup.find('div', {'id': 'fak_id_7a3586aa7b32182f036c0dab143d2df8_493'})
    eduDirections = [{'title': i.get_text()} for i in eduDirection.find_all('div', class_='grpPeriod')]
    print(eduDirections)
```